# Как установить размер заглушки ImageView не зная точных размеров получаемого изображения?

Tags: android, picasso

Есть LinearLayout, в который добавляется N'ое количество ImageView. Изображения загружаются с помощью библиотеки "Picasso":

```
Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(listUrls.get(0))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.img_holder)
                    .into(postImage);
```

Собственно вопрос по заглушке для ImageView `.placeholder(R.drawable.img_holder)` - заглушка не соответствует размеру изображения, игнорирует ScaleType.
Точный размер изображения до его скачивания узнать невозможно (изображения тянутся с Vk)
Как в таком случае подстроить заглушку по размер изображения?

Comment: Можно использовать `VectorDrawable`, с некоторых пор он включен в библиотеку поддержки и доступен на всех актуальных API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов. Каждый из них имеет свои особенности. Один из них - не использовать метод `placeholder(int res)`, а установить заглушку стандартными средствами в разметке атрибутом src.

Так все параметры типа ScaleType будут задействованы.

Comment: cейчас проверил (на одном изображении в LinearLayout пока что), да, вы правы. А по скольку VK API отдает нам размеры исходного изображения, мы можем получить размер того изображения, которое мы скачиваем: `scaleFactor = srcWidth / srcHeight`, после делим скачиваемый размер на наш `scaleFactor `. Спасибо, вы спасли мою ночь:)